# IDE that allows you to jump to implementation for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in the Java IDE I can click an object or function and directly be taken to the file (class) that the implementation lives in. My background has been mostly back-end java coding and front end JSP/JSF type of work and this never been a problem. Now I am working in a front-end environment that is all Javascript/AngularJS that is a ton of small .js files instead of .java files in different folders/packages.

I am trying to understand what's going on because I haven't wrote the code and it would be helpful if I could click on a function, service, provider etc and be taken directly to the .js file it lives in. Is there a IDE that can do that for AngularJS? I assume the only reason like IntelliJ and Eclipse can do that for Java is because each class imports at the top but in AngularJS it's done differently.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Comment: This question is going to be closed since we don't handle software requests on Stack Overflow (check out [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)) but check out WebStorm. It's pretty good for that and it's part of the IntelliJ family of IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

[Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)  (pure JS)

[PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (php + JS)

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) ( java + JS)

All of them are completely customizable by installing plugins